# Calling external function, unable to specify types C++/MVS

Tags: c++, dll

I am following [this tutorial](https://guidedhacking.com/threads/how-to-call-a-game-function.7825/) for accessing functions stored in a 3rd party `.dll`. (For full disclosure, I am **not** trying to hack a video game, I just need to use the same tools).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (v141) and my current code looks like this:

```
if (HMODULE const hLib = LoadLibraryA(PATH_TO_LIB)) {
    typedef IServer(__cdecl * _Create)(char* version);

    _Create Create_addr = (_Create)GetProcAddress(hLib, "Create");
}
```

I am trying to call the function `IServer Create(char* version)` stored in the `.dll`, the type `IServer` is also defined in the `.dll`. After running `dumpbin` I can confirm that the function is exported correctly.

I have also imported the header file containing the `IServer` definition.

The issue is that, according to visual studio:

- In lieu of `__cdecl *` it "`expected a type specifier`"
- At `(char* GameServerInterfaceVersion)`, it claims "`a function returning function is not allowed`"
- On the last line, `_CreateGameServer` is apparently an "`unidentified identifier`"

I believe I have followed the tutorial to the letter and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

How can I get VS to recognize these types?

Comment: did you check with ``dumpbin /EXPORTS dllname`` if the dll exports a "Create" function?

Comment: I'll do that and report back

Comment: @BitTickler Can confirm it is exported correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to define IServer first and then the errors will disappear

Comment: Is `typedef` not where `IServer` is defined?

Comment: In any case, I have imprted the header file that contains the `IServer` definition

Comment: @JessicaChambers in this example IServer is the return type of the function you're typedeffing

Comment: Yes? I'm not sure I understand.

Should the typedef not be called `IServer`?

Comment: @JessicaChambers in this example, you're creating a typedef for a function pointer.  IServer is is the return type, __cdecl is the calling convention, _Create is the name of the typedef.  Then you get the address of the real function using GetProcAddress and you create a function pointer which points to this function, using the _Create typedef by casting it.  I hope that helps

Comment: Is that not what I did?

Comment: Or should it be `typedef  _CreateGameServer(__cdecl * IGameServer)`?

Comment: @JessicaChambers one of these things is a return type, the other is the name of your typedef.  The name of your typedef comes after the __cdecl *.  The return type is before the parenthesis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217044/discussion-between-guidedhacking-and-jessica-chambers).